# Wordpress CSS not displaying navigation correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I created a website on wordpress and the second tier menus (display if you click 'Clothing' or 'Bags') starts underneath the parent page

I would like to be in line with the first level menu regardless on whether you click 'Clothing' or 'Bags'

http://www.dawaf.co.uk/showroom/bags

```
/*Main Navigation
------------------------------------------------------------ */
#access {
    background: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: -10px auto 6px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#access div {
    margin: 0 0.5%;
}

#access a {
    color: #EEEEEE;
    line-height: 2.2;
    padding: 0 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
}



#access ul ul {
    width: 800px;
}

#access ul ul a {
    width: auto;
    background: transparent !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#access ul ul li:hover a {
    color: #666666;
}

#access li.current_page_item  ul {
    display: block;
}

#access li:hover > a {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #666;
}

#access ul li:hover > ul {
display: none;
}

#access ul li.current_page_item:hover > ul {
display: block;
}

/*Submenu
------------------------------------------------------------ */

#access ul ul {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#access ul ul a {
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    line-height: 0.4;
}

#access li:hover > a, #access ul ul :hover > a, #access a:focus {
    background: #FFF;
}

ul.children {
    width: 1000px !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    margin-top: -15px !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want them in-line as in to the right of the top-menu items?
ie:

Clothing - Bags > Day | Evening

Or do you want them to line-up under the top-menu row at the same left position on the page?
ie:

Clothing - Bags
Day | Evening

Clothing - Bags
Dresses | Jumpsuits

Either way you'll want to play with the "#access ul ul" css properties. Your second level menu is a ul nested within the ul of your main level menu. If you can't get the control you want as it is, you might want to break out the second level menu into it's own ul that's not nested.

Comment: I want them to line up under the top menu at the same left position on the page

Answer (score 0):

i can't find the right stuff in the code you've posted, but at your site i suggest that you try moving the `position:relative` option from your `#access li` (style.css line 562) to `#access ul` (style.css line 556)